# New column receives the value Null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|CommunityId|nodes_count|edges_count|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         26|          3|         11|
|        964|         16|         18|
|       1806|          9|         31|
|       2040|         13|         12|
|       2214|          8|          8|
|       2927|          7|          7|
```

Then I add the column `Rate` as follows:

```
df
  .withColumn("Rate",when(col("nodes_count") =!= 0, (lit("edges_count")/lit("nodes_count")).as[Double]).otherwise(0.0))
```

This is what I get:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|CommunityId|nodes_count|edges_count|                   Rate|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|         26|          3|         11|                   null|
|        964|         16|         18|                   null|
|       1806|          9|         31|                   null|
|       2040|         13|         12|                   null|
|       2214|          8|          8|                   null|
|       2927|          7|          7|                   null|
```

For some reason `Rate` is always equal to `null`.

Comment: you're trying to divide strings and then cast the result as double?!

Comment: @philantrovert: No, it's not true. This is the output of printSchema(): `root
 |-- CommunityId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- nodes_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- edges_count: long (nullable = true)`

Comment: You are using `lit` inappropriately is what I meant. `lit` will pass it as a literal so your query essentially becomes `"edges_count"/"nodes_count"`

Comment: @philantrovert: Ahh, I see. That's because I was using `lit("...")` instead of `lit($"..")`.

Comment: `lit($"...")` is incorrect. Use just `$"..."` or `'colname` or `col(colname)`

Comment: @philantrovert: Ok, I see. Yes, indeed `lit` is used when there is, for example, a numeric value that should be multiplied by a column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you use `lit`. You should use `col` instead:

```
df
  .withColumn(
    "Rate" ,when(col("nodes_count") =!= 0,
    (col("edges_count") / col("nodes_count")).as[Double]).otherwise(0.0))
```

although both `when` and as `Double` are useless here, and simple division would be more than sufficient:

```
df.withColumn("Rate", col("edges_count") / col("nodes_count"))
```

Comment: What happens when `nodes_count` is equal to 0?